# Any Open-Source, Free Software That Can Be Used to Computationally Calculate Binding Affinity Between Two Molecules?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

There are programs out there which calculate the binding affinity between a ligand and a target protein (Autodock 4, Autodock Vina, Chimera... etc). Is there any analogous program that can be used to calculate the binding affinities between two molecules?

For my purposes, I'd like to computationally determine the binding affinity between crystalline hydroxyapatite and an analogue of a bisphosphonate molecule.

Comment: Software recommendation is not really on topic here, but it might be on [mattermodeling.se]. Please check their guidelines before asking there. I'm afraid this question has a high chance of being closed here.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I will switch forums immediately.

Comment: Before you do that, I've already asked in chat there. So we'll might get a hint soon. And if it's in topic we can simply migrate it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross posted to a different site: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8489/49